# Junit Integration Testing in 3 layer Architecture

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

So i have to write a integration test for my project which is about managing employee and organized by 3 layer architecture , it just have 3 functionality insert, update, delete. Since i have lack experience in testing so i'm confused one thing that if i write test for one functionality like insert employee, which class i have to call to test for that functionality , Business Layer or Data Access Layer ??
Thanks for your answers
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your unit testing you can test Business and Data access layer separately,

Since you want to implement Integration test, i would suggest to test Business layer directly,  which will in-turn test your DAL too(If you are not using any mocking framework)